# Reaction with tin(IV) iodide and hydrogen peroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Today I reacted tin(IV) iodide $\ce{SnI4}$ (dissolved in water) with hydrogen peroxide. This produced a yellow/brown colour (I'm guessing due to formation of $\ce{I2}?).$

I then added some petroleum spirit which gave a bi-phasic system which was a clear/pink/ light purple colour on top and an orange-brown yellow underneath.

I'm struggling to find out what reactions have occurred here, can anyone please help?

Comment: I propose the following equation :
SnI4 + 2 H2O2 --> SnO2 + 2 H2O + 2 I2

Comment: $\ce{SnI4}$ quickly hydrolyses in water, so likely there will be hexahydroxostannic acid that hydrogen peroxide actually encounters.

Comment: Ahh ok, this would make sense, thank you for your quick reply! Would this explain the colours in each layer?

Comment: how would this account for the colours?

Comment: Clear/pink color is likely due to Mie scattering of white $\ce{SnO2}$ particles (sol formed from $\ce{H2[Sn(OH)6]}$), and orangey brown color is probably iodine from the reaction between HI (product of hydrolysis of $\ce{SnI4}$) and $\ce{H2O2}$. Do you need references from reputable literature sources to back this up? If so, feel free to add `reference-request` tag, I'll try to look them up and maybe post an answer with reactions.

Comment: Just in case, are you sure the brown yellow phase was underneath, and the clear pink one was on top and not vice versa? Also, are you sure it was an ordinary petroleum ether? If you have a photo, it would be nice to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>**Note**: this is a preliminary description, which I think answers the question, but disagrees in one detail (see asterisk).</sub>

Tin(IV) iodide is completely hydrolyzed by water [1, p. 120] to colorless hexahydroxostannic acid:

$$\ce{SnI4 + 6 H2O <=> H2[Sn(OH)6] + 4 HI}$$

Hydrogen peroxide can not oxidize $\ce{Sn^4+}$ further (in fact, [hexahydroxostannate(IV) is used as a stabiliser for hydrogen peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_stannate)), and is likely going to oxidize hydroiodic acid to iodine (which attributes to the brown color) instead:

$$\ce{H2O2 + 2 HI -> I2 + 2 H2O}$$

Hexahydroxostannic acid only exists in solution and tends to form cloudy/milky gel over time [2, p. 1021]; this can be simplified as formation of colloidal particles of tin(IV) oxide [hydrates]:

$$\ce{H2[Sn(OH)6] <=> SnO2 · n H2O + $(4-n)$ H2O}$$

When petroleum ether is added, iodine is extracted to organic phase (on top due to lower density of the ether). Tin(IV) oxide sol remains in aqueous phase and attributes to its slightly pink color due to [Mie scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering) of colloidal solution.*

* Phase order doesn't match OP's description which suggests opposite coloring of the phases (additional clarification on the type of petroleum spirit or a photo of the binary phase mixture would help).

#### References

1. Inorganic Syntheses; Bailar, J. C., Ed.; *Inorganic Syntheses*; John Wiley & Sons, Inc.: Hoboken, NJ, USA, **1953**; Vol. 4. https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470132357.
2. Holleman, A. F.; Wiberg, E.; Wiberg, N. *Lehrbuch der anorganischen Chemie*, 102nd ed.; Fischer, G., Ed.; Walter de Gruyter: Berlin New York, **2007**. ISBN 978-3-11-017770-1. (in German)

Comment: Thank you so much for this description, although yes the top layer was slightly pink but I suppose I should have described it as more clear? I’m not quite sure what’s going on @andselisk

Comment: @andelisk I should have taken a picture, I didn’t think at the time! I guess the top layer was just off a light purple, not a milky colour

Comment: @MarinaCalder Hmm, it's indeed hard to discuss colors in the absence of a photo. Purple color might be due to iodine remaining in aqueous phase. And by "milky" I didn't mean plain white, but a cloudy-white colloid solution, [something like this](http://cdn.instructables.com/F4H/3QPD/I5TI2DEX/F4H3QPDI5TI2DEX.LARGE.jpg) (randomly picked from Google Images).

Comment: Which iodide is extracted to organic phase? Would it not be the iodi**ne** - I don't understand how the iodide would prefer a non-polar solvent.

Comment: @StianYttervik You are absolutely correct, this was a typo. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it so much!:) @andselisk